# $ \rm\LaTeX $ and $ \mathit Mathematica $: a versus $ a $

Tags: latex, fonts

There are many questions on this site about making the fonts in *Mathematica* commensurate with the default *Computer modern* font in $ \rm\LaTeX $. I'm not interested in complex workarounds, using the wonderful *MaTeX* package and such because `FontFamily ->"Times"` is (almost) adequate. There is really just one single character that causes my problems:  **a**.

[image]

Notice in this short example that the **a** in the *Mathematica* figure differs significantly from the **a** in $ \rm\LaTeX $. My ideal solution would be some way to replace the **a** in the *Mathematica* `Times` font with one that matches *Computer modern*'s.

Of course in the long run, we all desperately urge WRI to incorporate *Computer modern* naturally into their font list.  (Frankly, I think it should be their default font.)

I don't think CMU seriph is appropriate, since it has the same (big loop) a as *Mathematica*, as this screenshot of the CMU seriph download page shows:

[image]

Comment: You could always install the Computer Modern fonts (or rather the open CMU fonts)? That's what I did and it's been great ever since.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Computer Modern and Times use the very same style for `a`.  This is roman vs italic in each: http://i.stack.imgur.com/G2KfG.png  Are you referring to the difference between roman and italic rather than Times and Computer Modern?

Comment: What you show in the *last* screenshot are the math mode fonts, which are italic. You seem to be comparing it with the upright version of Times. Your first screenshot shows formulas which use both bold and normal weight fonts. The bold one is traditionally set as upright. You'd get the very same look with CM. http://i.stack.imgur.com/DUTB8.png

Comment: @Szabolcs:  Yes... you are correct.  Thanks.  I suppose I should merely use non-italics for the *Mathematica* characters to be consistent.  (I wonder why the fundamental shape is so different for normal versus italics.)